# How to install bonfire for codeigniter on a shared server that only allows one single database

Tags: codeigniter, installation, manual

my hosting company only allow one single mysql database. this database can only be created through the cpanel interface. as such providing the databse details in the bonfire install screen fails. is there a manual way to setup the bonfire application with the correct folder structure and database configuration?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

if the script can, why you not? But, when bonfire fails on create, i make this steps:
- verify if my host allow url rewrite, or chenge in config on index_path to "index.php"
- verify the folder "Modules" has permission 777